# sudo overrides ifconfig wrapper, how to stop this

Tags: linux, bash, raspbian, sudo, ifconfig

I have put together a wrapper for ifconfig as I want users to be allowed to change only eth0 and not eth1.

The wrapper looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
function containsIntf()
{
    # find interface from $@.
    local needle="$1"

    shift

    # Separates strings in the array for matching. Must be extremely-unlikely
    # to appear in the input array or the needle.
    local delimiter='#!-\8/-!#'

    # Create a string with containing every (delimited) element in the array,
    # and search it for with grep in fixed-string mode.

    if printf "${delimiter}%s${delimiter}" "$@" | \grep --fixed-strings --quiet "${delimiter}${needle}${delimiter}"; then
        return 0
    fi

    return 1
}

ifconfig(){
    local array=( $@ )          # get all args in an array
    local len=${#array[@]}          # find the length of an array
    local host=${array[$len-1]}     # get the last arg
    local args=${array[@]:0:$len-1} # get all args before the last arg in $@ in an array





if ! containsIntf "eth1" "${array[@]}" ; 
then 
    local _ifconfig="/sbin/ifconfig"
    # pass args and host
    $_ifconfig "${array[@]}"
else

echo "Denied"

fi;
}
```

Now when I use it in raspbian without sudo, it displays interface information but will not allow any change. so ifconfig eth0 down will not do anything.

sudo ifconfig eth0 down will take eth0 down, but it will also work with sudo ifconfig eth1 down, which I do not want.

is there anyway I can prevent sudo overriding the wrapper but allowing it to work?

Comment: Did you use an alias to do the wrapping ? Something like `alias ifconfig=my_wrapper.sh` in your .bashrc or .profile files ?

Comment: Check this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269078/executing-a-bash-script-function-with-sudo).